# devise_token_auth email sending issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, mailgun

I'm using `devise_token_auth` in my app. When user registers, it automatically sends confirmation email.

from https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/registrations_controller.rb

```
# ..code
unless @resource.confirmed?
# user will require email authentication
  @resource.send_confirmation_instructions({
    client_config: params[:config_name],
    redirect_url: @redirect_url
})
# ..code
```

And I get 500 error.

```
I, [2016-09-01T12:32:06.142856 #15153]  INFO -- : [07ca58ab-1797-4edb-99bb-c7d408bfd2c9] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 31331ms (ActiveRecord: 8.4ms)
F, [2016-09-01T12:32:06.145874 #15153] FATAL -- : [07ca58ab-1797-4edb-99bb-c7d408bfd2c9]   
F, [2016-09-01T12:32:06.146192 #15153] FATAL -- : [07ca58ab-1797-4edb-99bb-c7d408bfd2c9] Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired):
F, [2016-09-01T12:32:06.146249 #15153] FATAL -- : [07ca58ab-1797-4edb-99bb-c7d408bfd2c9]   
F, [2016-09-01T12:32:06.146292 #15153] FATAL -- : [07ca58ab-1797-4edb-99bb-c7d408bfd2c9] /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:542:in `initialize'
...
```

As you can see from the log it times out `Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired):`

But when I run `User.last.send_confirmation_instructions` from console it sends the email how it is suppose to be.

What am I suppose to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of ipv6.

To fix it I had to edit `/etc/gai.conf` by uncommenting `#precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100` line